# Does Qiskit allow for QASM 3.0 code to be utilized?

Tags: qiskit, qasm

I am interested in using QASM 3.0 after reading it's documentation and seeing it's examples [1](https://github.com/openqasm/openqasm). However, I see that in IBM Quantum Experience QASM 3.0 is not supported yet. Is there any way I can run QASM 3.0 code locally or by a customized Qiskit install? Also is QASM 3.0 still in active development and is there a timeline? Long story short I feel like there is documentation I am just missing/not finding.

Answer (score 3):

[OpenQASM 3](https://openqasm.com/) is under active developement (as in July 2022), [with several working groups](https://github.com/openqasm/openqasm/blob/main/WG.md) that are [adding new features regularly](https://github.com/openqasm/openqasm/pulls).

I am not aware of a timeframe, but you can ask in the `#open-qasm` channel in [the Qiskit Slack](https://ibm.co/joinqiskitslack) and watch the recordings on the OpenQASM 3 TSC Meeting (links in the same slack channel).

At the moment (July 2022), Qiskit support for OpenQASM3 is limited. It does not have an importer (OpenQASM3 -> Qiskit) but it has some sopport for exporting (Qiskit -> OpenQASM3). For example:

```
from qiskit import qasm3, QuantumCircuit

qc = QuantumCircuit(2,1)
qc.h(0)
qc.cx(0, 1)
qc.measure(0,0)
qc.x(1).c_if(0, 0)

print(qasm3.dumps(qc))
```

```
OPENQASM 3;
include "stdgates.inc";
bit[1] c;
qubit[2] _all_qubits;
let q = _all_qubits[0:1];
h q[0];
cx q[0], q[1];
c[0] = measure q[0];
if (c[0] == 0) {
  x q[1];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the update. I had already noticed the ability to go Qiskit->QASM, and I appreciate the clarification.